# AsyncTask is taking 3 seconds in localhost json reading

Tags: android

this is mycode please suggest how to speed up ,its getting very slow,taking 5 seconds at the first time the next time its taking 3 seconds

```
public ArrayList<HealthBean> getIPList(String user,String mac) {

        ArrayList<HealthBean> list=new ArrayList<HealthBean>();
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client", user));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mac", mac));
        Log.d(login_tag, params.toString());
        JSONObject json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getIPList, params);        
        Log.d(login_tag, params.toString());

        try {
            int status=json.getInt("success");
            System.out.println("---------------------"+status);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jArray = json.getJSONArray("products");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                HealthBean bean=new HealthBean();
                bean.setIp(json_data.getString("ip"));
                bean.setDb(json_data.getInt("db"));
                bean.setLinux(json_data.getInt("linux"));
                bean.setSlave(json_data.getInt("slave"));
                bean.setApplication(json_data.getString("app"));
                bean.setDbPort(json_data.getString("mysql_port"));
                bean.setLinuxPort(json_data.getString("linux_port"));

                list.add(bean);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        


        return list;
    }
```

//parsing the json

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) { 
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 int i=0;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

Comment: What's taking the time? Accessing the URL or parsing the JSON?

Comment: i think both, please suggest me how to calculate the time for each process

Comment: Please, format your post, so that the code gets close to each part. Then, paste the JSON that is being used.

Comment: Well, easiest thing to do would be to put log messages before and after each part, and check the logcat - it has timestamps.

Comment: Moreover, i suggest you move on to google's own volley library to make network calls and use model classes to set your data. This is a more modular and a much better approach

Answer (score 0):

Please try using retrofit/volley to get better performance in querying API's (any network calls).

There are benchmarks and test results given at following link.

http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

In case if you think your purpose will be solved with retrofit (My personal choice), you can look for tutorials at 
http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-retrofit-tutorial/

hope this helps.

Comment: i tried volley that also is taking almost this timing maximum i can get half second variation

Comment: okay. can you post profiling results along with the code and in case if your profiling results show that its server side call that is causing this delay. can you post server side code as well ?